# How to use wx-config information in makefile for setting compiler/linker variables?

Tags: makefile, wxwidgets, libs

I have an application base on wxwidgets, using the boost and pcre lib. 
Inside the makefile I have normally to put compiler and linker paths by using the CXXFLAGS variable etc.

I wrote this:

```
CXXFLAGS := -I. -I/path/boost/prod -I/path/pcre/include $(shell path/wxWidgets/bin/wx-config  --unicode=yes --static=yes --cxxflags) -DPCRE_STATIC -O3

CPPFLAGS := -I. -I/path/boost/prod -I/path/pcre/include $(shell path/wxWidgets/bin/wx-config --unicode=yes --static=yes --cppflags) -DPCRE_STATIC -O3

LDFLAGS := -L. -L/path/pcre/lib -L/path/wxWidgets/lib $(shell $path/wxWidgets/bin/wx-config --unicode=yes --static=yes --optional-libs html,aui,stc,xml,adv,core,base) -lpcre -O3
    EXEC_POST
```

From what I now, wx-config tells me which libraries I need.

When I try to link my compiled files, the linker puts an error for not finding e.g. the library "gio-2.0", which is one of the libraries wx-config stated. I can now install all of those not found libraries manually and it work, but normally all this demanded libs should be part of wxwidgets.... I think I messed up with the parts in the above written makefile configuration. What do you think?

Comment: `-I` and `-L` take single path arguments, not multiple path arguments. You need `-I/-L` before each of your manual paths.

Comment: I use them, I just wrote above path instead the whole path with -I -L. Will edit above to make it more clear.

Comment: Is there a gio-2.0 library in the wxWidgets/lib directory? Just because wxWidgets depends on it doesn't mean it includes it.

Comment: You are sure wx-config states libs which aren't part it? If yes, how can I state in the makefile to include a manually installed lib staticly in the binary?

Comment: I am certain that if wxWidgets requires the gio library from glib that it may not include that library as part of its sources and instead depend on the system to provide that library. If that is the case then you need that installed to link against at build time. In which case you would just need to have that installed to statically link to it the same as any other library you want to statically link against. I assume that your answer indicates that there is no gio library under the wxWidgets/lib path?

Comment: Exactly. I would highly appreciate it if you would let me know, how to I link a library static to the binary. Is it enough the library to be static and not shared?

Comment: Presumably you are already linking wxWidgets into your binary statically, no? In which case doing so with gio should be no different. You should just need to make sure that a static version is available for linking and you are telling the linker you want it to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `--libs` instead of `--optional-libs`.

Also, you don't need the explicit `-L/path/wxWidgets/lib`, this is already output by `wx-config`.

Comment: Good hint, but unfortunately it doen't change anything. I figured out, that you can include libraries when building wxwidgets. Will try that out.

Comment: Only partial success with this approach, since there some libs which cannot be included by building wxWidgets. But I read, that it makes a difference on which system wxWidgets was compiled. That means, in order to not have linking problems, you should have wxWidgets built before on the same system you want to compile. Does this make sense?

Comment: Yes, if the system where you're trying to use `wx-config` doesn't have the libraries which were present on the system where this `wx-config` was created, it's definitely not going to work.